# My wix website is very, very slow seems like its because of JS

Tags: java, wix

I have small jewelry website built on wix.
Its very slow .. takes around 8 seconds to load up.
i tested it on gtmetrix.com
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.ardonn.co.il/1Vprfypw/
And it appears that most of the slowness is due to Java script.
Not im not sure why this happens, there really arent any fancy things on the page just an image and some text.
Perhaps a search bar in the header.. am i missing something?
How do i isolate and remove the culprit?
Thanks to everyone that helps!

Comment: It’s JavaScript by the way, not Java script. An important distinction. // Unfortunately, there is no “web design” Stack Exchange. With Wix, it’s not even general web design either. Your best bet is to find a Wix-specific community and ask there.